# Классический вид меню виджетов

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, интерфейс

Открыл пункт меню в Wordpress Внешний вид -> Виджеты. Получил следующее окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите что нужно сделать, чтобы отображалось не гутенберговское окно для настройки виджетов, а отображалось окно как на [Видеоурок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_m1Fs7_va8E&list=PL3LQJkGQtzc6Nwz67GGrMdqxim1c0H5DC&index=4&t=185s) на 9:50. Даже не знаю как загуглить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установите плагин [Classic Widgets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-widgets/).

Answer (score 2):

Используйте пару хуков (код можно разместить в **functions.php** активной темы, например):

```php
<?php
// Отключает редактор блоков на странице виджетов
// при использовании плагина Gutenberg.
add_filter( 'gutenberg_use_widgets_block_editor', '__return_false' );

// Отключает редактор блоков на странице виджетов
// без использования плагина.
add_filter( 'use_widgets_block_editor', '__return_false' );
```